# Reactjs Helmet, GoogleSEO

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

Does somebody know about a Helmet in ReactJS (https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). I try to use Helmet for google seo.

```
<Helmet>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} />
</Helmet>
```

Why comes mistakes in console?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount has been [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

> These [methods are considered legacy](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting) and you should avoid them in new code:

Comment: componentDidMount which comes later in the lifecycle can be used https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: However, I would recommend getting familiar with the new Hooks API. 
Lifecycle methods can be confusing and the trend in React development is to generally use Hooks instead, whenever possible.






https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: Can somebody give an example. These materials are too much difficult to understand. I can read by working helmet-using example only.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with your lifecycle method?